# Image в crispyforms Django

Tags: python, django, django-model, django-view

Пытаюсь запилить возможность прикреплять изображение при создании поста. MEDIA URL есть. В итоге, при создании поста, есть название, контент, а изображения нет (папка post_pics пуста).

Возможно дело в crispyforms. Надо как-то настроить на работу с файлами и директориями, но вообще не уверен.

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
    PostListView,
    PostCreateView,
)
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='blog-home'),
    path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
]
```

views.py

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content', 'image']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_pics/', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.date_posted >= (timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=7))
```

и post_form.html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <div class = "content-section">
        <form method = "POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class = "form-group">
                <legend class = "border-bottom mb-4">Question Post</legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class = "form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type = "submit">Post</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files, название главы Binding uploaded files to a form.

Было так:

```
<form method = "POST">
```

Надо так:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method = "POST">
```